# how to display the sum of 5 input numbers from user using c language

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {
    float num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum;

    printf("Enter a Number between");
    fflush;
    scanf("%f",&num1);
    fflush;

    printf("Enter a Number between");
    scanf("%f",&num2);
    fflush;

    printf("Enter a Number between");
    scanf("%f",&num3);
    fflush;

    printf("Enter a Number between");
    scanf("%f",&num4);
    fflush;

    printf("Enter a Number between");
    scanf("%f",&num5);
    fflush;

    sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
    printf("The sum of the five numbers you have entered is %f",sum);

    getch();
}
```

I am a newbie in c programming. We have an assignment and I have created the above code. But we need a shorter solution. The user must input five numbers and display the sum. Can you please help me to translate this code using do while function or post test loop. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does the assignment tell you an upper limit on how many numbers will be entered?  (5, I guess.)  Does the assignment tell you how the user will tell you they're done entering numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to input numbers (say `5` in this case) and add it with value stored in `sum` in each iteration.

```
     int num , sum = 0;  

     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         scanf("%d", &num);  
         sum += num;
     }
```

Comment: Why provide a complete solution when he is clearly trying to learn?

Comment: @RedX; I also realized I should not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cycle to read 5 values and accumulate their sum. I prefer to leave you with this hint only because this seems like a homework assignment. You may reuse the same variable reading 5 different inputs and have a separate variable in which you accumalate the sum. You can also use a for cycle instead of the `do... while` you seem to be using.

Comment: I tried to use this code:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main(){
 int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,sum,noOfInputs=1;
 printf("Enter a Number");
 scanf("%i",&num1);
 fflush;
 do{
  printf("Enter another number");
  scanf("%i",&num2,&num3,&num4,&num5);
  noOfInputs++;
 }
 while(noOfInputs<5);
 sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5;
 printf("The sum of the five numbers you have entered is %i",sum);
 getch();
}


but it doesnt give me correct total..please help

Comment: @ray If you want to store all the numbers, you'll need to use an array (such as `float num[5]` and store the value in `num[i]`). Otherwise you can do the sum inside the loop and use only one variable for all the inputs.

Comment: @ray Also, `n=1; do {...; n++;}while(n<5)` is (in this case) equivalent to `for(n=1;n<5;n++){...}`

Comment: @ray I have added some more tips in my answer. You can have another look.

Answer (score 0):

When someone asks me to do their homework for them, I enjoy coming up with a slightly convoluted, but functionally correct answer. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    float numbers[5] = {0.0F};
    float sum = 0.0F;
    int count = 5;

    while(count --> 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a number for entry %d: ", 5-count);
        scanf("%f",numbers+count);
        sum += numbers[count];
    }
    printf("The sum is %f\n", sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```